# Responsive navbar will not "stretch"

Tags: html, css, responsive

My website has a 3 item in nav menu, I've turned off the responsive menu toggle, and want it to drop below the logo in `tablet` and `mobile`. However, I'm unable to do that. I just want navbar to drop a line and retain the same look.

**Screengrab**
[Full width vs mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJ24.png)

I've placed `block` on both `.srt-menu` classes in both the full size and 480 screens, but nothing works. Also declared a width for each menu item, or removing all block displays and using `float`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the HTML code:

```
<header class="wrapper clearfix">

    <div id="banner">        
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/header.png" alt="logo"></a></div> 
    </div>

    <!-- main navigation -->
    <nav id="topnav" role="navigation">
      <ul class="srt-menu" id="menu-main-navigation">          
          <li class="about"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
          <li class="gallery"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
          <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>   
      </ul>     
    </nav><!-- end main navigation -->

</header>
```

```css
#menu-main-navigation{
  display:block;
}

.srt-menu, .srt-menu * {
  margin:           0;
  padding:      0;
  list-style:       none;
}

.srt-menu ul {
  position:     absolute;
  display:none;
  width: 12em; /* left offset of submenus need to match (see below) 
  */
}

.srt-menu ul li {
  width: 20%;
}

.srt-menu li:hover {
  visibility:       inherit; /* fixes IE7 'sticky bug' */
}

.srt-menu li {
  float:            left;
  position:     relative;
  margin-left:1px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.srt-menu li li {
  margin-left:0px;
}

.srt-menu a {
  display:      block;
  position:     relative;
}

#topnav, .srt-menu {
  float:right;
  margin: 1.2em 0 0 0;
}

.srt-menu a {
  text-decoration:none;
  color: #000000;
}

.srt-menu li a {
  background:#fff;
  margin:0; 
  padding:0px 25px;
  height:45px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.srt-menu a, .srt-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
  color: #000000;   
}

/*LARGER MOBILE DEVICES
This is for mobile devices with a bit larger screens.*/
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #banner{
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    margin-bottom:20px;/*this depends on the height of the logo*/
  }

  .topnav {
    float:left; 
    margin: .2em;
  }

  .srt-menu, ul.srt-menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you also attach an image?

Comment: Photo added to post.

Comment: You can simply achieve this by using `media-queries`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I guess I needed to write out the problem.

I made a navbar with different colored buttons and hover effects, but I didn't specify 'inline-block' for them. In full-width, the navbar inherited margins and widths from the parent div.

Basically, change a block to inline-block, tweaked some padding and margins.

```
.srt-menu li.about, .srt-menu li.gallery, .srt-menu li.contact {
display:inline-block;
margin:1px 0; 
padding:10px;
text-decoration:none;
font-size: 1.4em;

}
```